# Is there an XSD to validate JavaRosa XForm XML files?

Tags: xml, xsd, xforms, javarosa

What is the way to go to validate a [JavaRosa](https://bitbucket.org/javarosa/javarosa/wiki/Home) xml file ? Is there an official XSD or DTD ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For XForms itself, you can use W3C's [XForms-11-Schema.xsd](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/Forms/2007/XForms-11-Schema.xsd).

For JavaRosa form submissions, you can use their [OpenRosaMetaDataSchema](https://bitbucket.org/javarosa/javarosa/wiki/OpenRosaMetaDataSchema):

> There are two types of metadata in a form submission. The first
>   provides metadata about the identity and version of the XForm used to
>   create the data being submitted. The second captures useful
>   information about the submission itself.

Comment: This looks like a proposal, I have not seen xml files using such a structure so far (no `http://openrosa.org/xforms`), is it used by some project ?
Will there be conflicts with JavaRosa 'additions' and the XForms XSD ?

Comment: There is more about this here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/open-web-discuss/Bu0HeJxzQ-Q/ESUwyrJujeMJ